# How to read s3 xml response from iframe with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, iframe, amazon-s3, response

I have created a HTML form that post to my amazon s3 bucket through an iframe. It works and is fully functional. However, I've tried reading the response with jquery and keep getting this error

> Permission denied to access property 'ownerDocument'

I'm guessing this has to do with the crossdomain policy?

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#FileBrowser").change(function(){
        document.getElementById('MyForm').submit();
        $('iframe#targetFrame').load(function(){
            var Location = $(this).contents().find("Location").text();
            var ETag = $(this).contents().find("ETag").text();
            alert(LocationAdd+' '+ETag);//
        });
    });
});
```

The response I'm getting within the iframe:

```
<PostResponse>
<Location>http://MyBucket.s3.amazonaws.com/ThisIsMyFileLocation</Location>
<Bucket>MyBucket</Bucket>
<Key>ThisIsMyFileLocation</Key>
<ETag>"123456789123456789"</ETag>
</PostResponse>
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is cross domain policy restricting you, put in place to prevent XSS attacks. Without knowing the details of your setup...

Is it possible to save the data from remote to an intermediary placeholder? Some form of object or even a file?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. What I ended up doing is, when the upload was finished to redirect to a page on my server which would initiate a function. Not the best solution.... Good question, tho I think if you don't redirect on completion then you're taken to a results page on amazon. So not sure how you would be able to save that information being that the postresponse is only shown when the redirect is not used.